# How to extend an array of WP post objects from ACF with Timber\Post

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I am using WordPress, [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), and [Timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/) to build a theme. I am using an [ACF relationship field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) to choose featured posts for one of my pages. This relationship field returns an array of [WP post objects](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).

I grab this array and add it to my Timber `$context` with the following code:

```
/* featured posts */
$featured_posts = get_field('insights_featured_posts');
$context['featured_posts'] = $featured_posts;
```

I would like each of the [WP post objects](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) within this array to be extended using [Timber/Post](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/). I am not sure the best way to accomplish this with an array of post objects. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my twig file that accesses the `$featured_posts` array:

```
{% for post in featured_posts %}
 <div class="col ns-col-is-4">
 <h3 class="post-heading">{{post.post_title}}</h3>
 <p class="post-content">{{post.post_excerpt}}</p>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Well the alternative would be to create a single post template then iterate through the posts and render each individual post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close!

```
{% for post in Post(featured_posts) %}
  <div class="col ns-col-is-4">
    <h3 class="post-heading">{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <p class="post-content">{{ post.preview }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The diff is the start of the loop `{% for post in Post(featured_posts) %}` This `Post()` method will convert that array to a `Timber\Post` object

Comment: Wow! I had no clue you could do that. Thank you!