# ACF Post Object in ACF custom block using timber/twig

Tags: twig, timber

I realize this is vague, but documentation is slim. Trying to get any data from either a post object field or relationship field to appear in a custom block using timber/twig. If it's on the first 2 pages of Google results, I likely tried it with no luck. My other custom blocks I don't have to create a corresponding php file, just a twig file that's pulling data from a single, simple setup for all custom blocks. Repeaters, Groups, Galleries, no problem. Post Objects or Relationships, bupkis. Any help appreciated.

official documentation did nothing: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#relationship-field.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292482/how-to-extend-an-array-of-wp-post-objects-from-acf-with-timber-post) and it resolved my problem. I'll be back to post a full breakdown so the question and answer are actually useful to others.